# Android/Wear OS - testing wrist flick gestures on android studio avd emulator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wear-os, android-virtual-device

i'm trying to figure out how to test the **flick wrist out** and **flick wrist in** gestures in android studio's avd.

Currently these simulated real world actions are supported on the emulator:

[image: avd emulator controls]

And from [android's training guide on wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/wrist-gestures), it appears that the **flick wrist out** and **flick wrist in** gestures are mapped to key events:
[image: flick wrist mapped to key events in android]

My question is, is it possible to map those key events (KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT and KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS) to the button actions on the avd emulator controls from the first image (button 1 and 2) and just test my code for the flick gestures from there if it works correctly?

Would be open to other suggestions on how to approach this as well. Thank you!